# Omnet++ Multisend with TCP

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have a distributed K-Fat-Tree network scenario where multiple clients send requests to any of the available servers managed with OMnet++ and inet framework. Once a single server receives an incoming message/packet from a client, I want to multisend this message to all available servers over the network. By multisend, I mean open n amount of distinct unicast connections from this server to all servers and kind of "broadcast" this message to all available servers. Do you know which predifined inet modules (inet/applications/tcpapp) allow this possibility?

I am currently using TcpBasicClientApp and TcpGenericServerApp but I am not sure this is achievable with the current simple modules.